# How To Update a Specific field in my Firestore Database in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Screenshot of my Firestore database structure]

How to access and update a specific field in flutter fireStore Database?

```
Future<void> updateMyOrder(String username, String status) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("checkout")
  .doc(username)
  .update({'cart.condition': status});
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: if you look at the screenshot, the 'cart' is a List of Map. And I want to update a specific field under 'cart' > 'condition', but it rather override the current data in the collection

Comment: In the screen shot link, I have circled the field i need to update, but it overrides the existing data(List of Maps)

Answer (score 1):

There is no field `cart.condition` in the document you show, as that'd be a map-field called `cart` with a subfield called `condition` in it.

I think you're trying to update a field of an array item, which is not possible in Firestore. The only array operations are [array-union](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), which adds a new item to an array if it's not already in there, and [array-remove](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array). Both of these require that you specify the entire array item, and not just one/some fields of it.

The only way to update a field in a Firestore document is to:

1. Load the document in your application code.
2. Get the entire array from it.
3. Modify the item in the array.
4. Write the entire array back to the database.

Comment: ooo ok. Meaning that, Firestore doesn't supporting updating array elements by its  index. Hence I need to read the entire document and modify the array in memory, then set or update the entire array docs...thank you Frank

Comment: _your recommended approach was succesfully... **thank you**_. **Below is the successful code** `Future<void> updateMyOrder(String username, Map<String, dynamic> oldData) {

    DocumentReference ref =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("checkout").doc(username);

    return ref.update({
      'cart': FieldValue.arrayRemove([oldData])
    }).then((value) {
      oldData.update('condition', (val) => oldData['condition'] == 'new' ? 'old' : 'new');
      return ref.update({
        'cart': FieldValue.arrayUnion([oldData])
      });
    });
  }`